# is there a way to make Icon come after the label in material ui chips component, without the use of onDelete?

Tags: material-ui

In material UI the Icon elemet of chips comes before the label, i want the Icon  to come after the label.

```
<Chip label="Online" Icon={ <InfoIcon/> }/>
```

Though there is a onDelete function that enables deleteIcon element like in this code.

```
const handleClose = () => {}

return (
    <Chip label={Online} onDelete={handleClose} deleteIcon={<InfoIcon />} />
)
```

The above code gives this [outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkXl4.png), though it is what i'm looking for, i would like to know is there any other way to get the same outcome without the use of onDelete altogether.